# ChromeProxyService:Failed to evaluate expression '_secondaryCompleter?.completeError': InternalError:Expression evaluation in async frames is not sup

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, service, proxy, expression-evaluation

I updated `Flutter` and `Chrome` version but non of them worked for me! I still get the following error when I try to run a Flutter Web application on Chrome:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
main.dart:1
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:43331/dCeVDxbe-OU=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:43331/dCeVDxbe-OU=/ws
 Running with sound null safety 
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:43331/dCeVDxbe-OU=/ws
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression '_secondaryCompleter?.completeError': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 14..
```

This is the result for `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10, on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 5.19.0-35-generic,
    locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.77.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

The following is the page I do get the error when I click on `Login` button:

```
import 'package:admin/modules/auth/providers/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AuthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthPage({super.key});
  static const routeName = '/auth';

  @override
  State<AuthPage> createState() => _AuthPageState();
}

class _AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  final Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
  };
  var _isLoading = false;

  Future<void> _submit() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      return;
    }

    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      await Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).signin(
        _authData['email'] as String,
        _authData['password'] as String,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      const errorMessage =
          'Could not authenticate you. Please try again later.';
      _showErrorDialog(error.toString());
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _showErrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('An Error Occurred!'),
        content: Text(message),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Okay'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Form(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'E-Mail',
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500)),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                  return 'Invalid email!';
                }
              },
              onSaved: (value) {
                _authData['email'] = value!;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500)),
              obscureText: true,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                  return 'Password is too short!';
                }
              },
              onSaved: (value) {
                _authData['password'] = value!;
              },
            ),
            if (_isLoading)
              const CircularProgressIndicator()
            else
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: _submit, child: Text('Login')),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```